# How to move LayoutBackground behind an ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I tried to add on the top right corner of my app a notificationBar which shows how many msgs are in the inbox. 
Later on I want to add a custom drawable to my background, for now I added only a black color as bg to reach my goal, as you can see on the left side of my image: This is a TextView constraint to the END of my ImageView. I want my Background to go behind the imageview BUT not to go outside of its dimensions neither to start before the imageview (you would see the top left and bottom right corner of the textview - rectangle

[image]

I'm stuck on that with the following Code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/msg_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"

        >

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 MSGs"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"

        />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_contact"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If no other view is constrained to the *TextView* you can simply apply a negative "x" translation to the *TextView*: 
`android:translationX="-15dp"`. I chose `-15dp` but it could be another negative value that works for your layout.

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/msg_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:text="0 MSGs"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:translationX="-15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_contact"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SebastienRieu's solution should work but you may need to add a margin to the start of the *TextView* to hide its top-left and bottom-left corners.

Answer (score 0):

change constraint of textview to start with imageView and add text alignment to textview

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/msg_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0 MSGs"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_contact" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout works as a frame layout.  For such designs, we can use guidelines. Guidelines work greats for such a view . 
I have made a few changes in your layout, I hope this can be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/msg_bar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_msg_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black_primary"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_28"
    android:text="0 MSGs"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_28"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_28"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_contact"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below link, you can use to get more info on guidelines https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html